# How do you train in a jutsu that kills you if used?

Tags: naruto

For example, Guy Sensei and Rock Lee can use the Eight Gates technique. If the last gate is opened, you die.

There is a lot of emphasis in the series that shows that one must train very hard to perfect a jutsu, technique, etc.

But how do you train and perfect something that you can only do once... and then just die?

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/how-does-guy-know-how-to-perform-the-jutsu-in-the-eight-gates-released-formation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's like jumping off a building.

You can jump from the first, second or third floor and survive. The method to reach all the floors remains the same *(Climbing by stairs... or you may call this training.)*.

However, after a certain number of floors, you will come to a realization that after you jump through this floor (let's just say the 20th -- *you need not practice climbing 20 floors for this -- the experience of climbing one floor is just fine)*, you will *become extinct*.

You don't need the experience nor practice to reach the 20th floor but you will surely *become extinct* if you jump from there.

Comment: this is interesting haha

Comment: sound funny and reasonable at the same time.

Comment: lol nice analogy after all